# Usage of Prism's DebugLogger

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism, xamarin-studio

I'm now trying to use `Log` method of `Prism.Logging.DebugLogger` of Prism6.1.0-pre5 on Xamarin.Forms to log my application.
But it does not output anything.

`DebugLogger` is implemented in [this](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Logging/DebugLogger.cs).
But In Assembly Browser, The line `Debug.WriteLine(messageToLog);` does not appear like this:
[image: this].

Does this relate about this probrem? How can I use it correctly?

Comment: How are you getting a reference to the logger?  Are you running in debug mode? Did you thoroughly check the output window?

Comment: @BrianLagunas I don't have any reference. I just found from Prism's source, and I was interested in using it. / Probably Yes, I'm running in debug mode with [Debug > iPhone 6s iOS 9.3]. Are there any option about Debug mode? / Yes, I checked output window. If I ran `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("hello");`, I got "hello" on my output window.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't output anything because, as you already saw in the decompiler(Xamarin Studio's Assembly Browser actually decompiles .NET code), the `Log` implementation doesn't do much, it just calls `string.Format`.

You're most probably using the release version of Prism.dll, probably got by NuGet, so the `Debug.WriteLine` was stripped out by compiler when Prism.dll was compiled for distribution to NuGet by the authors.

Another thing: the default logger created by Xamarin Forms `PrismApplicationBase` is `DebugLogger`.
When an error occurs when navigating to a Page(I have an error in XAML for example) the implementation in `PageNavigationService` calls default logger to write error and then throws the error:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Xamarin/Prism.Forms/Navigation/PageNavigationService.cs#L374

With the default logger error is not written for reasons above but even with the error being thrown by `PageNavigationService`, nothing gets displayed in the Output window, and app doesn't crash either.